# freebase mql - notable_types empty?

Tags: freebase, mql

I am sending the following mql query to get a list of topics, their mids and "notable types", but in the results notable types are always empty.

```
[{
  "name": "The beatles",
  "/common/topic/notable_types": [],             //also tried "null"
  "mid": null,
  "limit": 10
}]
```

But this is inconsistent with the online freebase. For example, the query returns 
    {
      "mid": "/m/07c0j",
      "/common/topic/notable_types": [],
      "name": "The Beatles"
    },

And by checking the webpage "http://www.freebase.com/m/07c0j" you can see it has a notable type of "music artist".

Any suggestions if I have used wrong query or anything to do with the freebase database?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They should really return on error on this query.  Notably types isn't available through the MQL API -- only the Topic API.